# Aws OpsWorks RDS Configuration for Tomcat context.xml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I am trying to deploy an app named abcd with artifact as abcd.war. I want to configure to an external datasource. Below is my abcd.war/META-INF/context.xml file

```
<Context>
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/abcdDataSource1" name="jdbc/abcdDataSource1" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/abcdDataSource2" name="jdbc/abcdDataSource2" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

I configured the below custom JSON during a deployment

```
{ 
    "datasources": { 
        "fa": "jdbc/abcdDataSource1", 
        "fa": "jdbc/abcdDataSource2" 
    }, 
    "deploy": { 
        "fa": { 
            "database": { 
                "username": "un", 
                "password": "pass", 
                "database": "ds1", 
                "host": "reserved-alpha-db.abcd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com", 
                "adapter": "mysql" 
            },
            "database": { 
                "username": "un", 
                "password": "pass", 
                "database": "ds2", 
                "host": "reserved-alpha-db.abcd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com", 
                "adapter": "mysql" 
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

I also added the recipe opsworks_java::context during configure phase. But it doesnt seem like working and I always get the message as below

[2014-01-11T16:12:48+00:00] INFO: Processing template[context file for abcd] action create (opsworks_java::context line 16)
[2014-01-11T16:12:48+00:00] DEBUG: Skipping template[context file for abcd] due to only_if ruby block

Can anyone please help on what I am missing with OpsWorks configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can only configure one datasource using the built-in database.yml. If you want to pass additional information to your environment, please see [Passing Data to Applications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/apps-data.html)